# Error: undefined control sequence missing = inserted for \ifnum

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, apacite, cite-package

I'm trying to write my paper with the Taylor & Francis LaTeX template. I get this error whenever I cite an author, although I have already entered all the references in **interactapasample.bib**.

```
    \documentclass[]{interact}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage[longnamesfirst,sort]{natbib}
    \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
    \renewcommand\bibfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
     \theoremstyle{plain}% Theorem-like structures provided by amsthm.sty
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
    \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
    
    \theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
    \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
    
    \theoremstyle{remark}
    \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
    \newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\begin{document}
   
\section{Introduction}\label{intro}

The smartphone is considered an essential component of modern life \cite{perez2016power}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{interactapasample}
\end{document}
```

What is displayed

```
<to be read again>
}
l.70
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
```

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` cannot be used directly together with `\usepackage[longnamesfirst,sort]{natbib}`. If you are using the T&F class I'm assuming you want to publish with them. Check what their submission guidelines/their template have to say about which bibliography/BibTeX styles are acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I want to publish with them. The template is not that clear. I put only 
`\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and the other one as a comment. Now I got this error `undefined control sequence`  `Underfull \hbox (badness 2103) in paragraph at line xx--xx`

Comment: Check with the submission guidelines of the journal which styles are acceptable. If APA style is acceptable and you want to use `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`, throw out `\usepackage[longnamesfirst,sort]{natbib}\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}` and use `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` instead.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Comment: How can we state that the problem is solved on this website?

Comment: I posted an answer with the content of the comments, which you can accept (by clicking the little checkmark on the top left of the answer): https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

`\bibliographystyle{apacite}` cannot be used directly together with `\usepackage[longnamesfirst,sort]{natbib}`.

If `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` is acceptable for the venue you are submitting to (check the submission guidelines and possibly additional comments in/documentation of your LaTeX template), replace

```
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,sort]{natbib}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
```

with

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

to use `natbib` commands with `apacite`.

Comment: That's clear. However, the editor mentions this: `\usepackage[longnamesfirst,sort]{natbib}% Citation support using natbib.sty

\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}% Citation support using natbib.sty
\renewcommand\bibfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% To set the list of references in 10 point font using natbib.sty
%\usepackage[natbibapa,nodoi]{apacite}% Citation support using apacite.sty. Commands using natbib.sty MUST be deactivated first! ` .

Comment: @kammad93 This does not appear to contradict what I wrote.

Comment: Yes totally. I didn't finish my question. If I chose `\usepackage[longnamesfirst,sort]{natbib}`, what can I write in `\bibliographystyle{}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. Knowing that the editor only provide `natbib.sty`

Comment: @kammad93 Lots of things. You could use the standard `natbib` styles for starters: `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` or `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`. But there are many, many, many other `natbib`-compatible styles out there (in fact `apacite` is more the exception than the rule). Of course I cannot tell you which are appropriate for submission for your journal. That is something the submission guidelines or hints in the template should make clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thank you for being patient with me.